# Проверка полей формы

Tags: php, форма

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Какой стандартный способ проверки всех полей формы на заполненность на стороне сервера на `PHP` (`+RegExp`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стандартных не бывает, практически каждая форма уникальна, да есть типовые, но...

```
class FormValidator {
    // First letter: a-z,A-Z, other: 0-9,a-z,A-Z,_
    function isLogin ($value) {  
        return (!empty($value) and preg_match('/[a-z]\w*/i',$value));  
    }
    // 0-9,a-z,A-Z,_
    function isWord ($value) {
        return (!empty($value) and preg_match('/\w+/i',$value));
    }
    function isYes($value) {
        return (!empty($value));
    }
}
class LoginForm extends FormValudator {
    var $login;
    var $password;
    var $remember;

    function __construct() {
        if (empty($_POST) or !is_array($_POST)) {
            throw new Exception('Form is empty');
        }
        foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
            switch ($name) {
                case "login":
                    if ($this->isLogin($value)) {
                        $this->login = $value;
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new Exception(
                            'login field is invalid'
                        );
                    }
                    break;
                case "password":
                    if ($this->isWord($value)) {
                        $this->password = $value;
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new Exception(
                            'password field is invalid'
                        );
                    }
                    break;
                case "remember":
                    if ($this->isYes($value)) {
                        $this->remember = $value;
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new Exception(
                            'remember field is invalid'
                        );
                    }
                    break;
                case "submit":
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

$e = null;
try {
    $login = new LoginForm (); 
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    die $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Пойду подучу ООП под `PHP` :-)

Comment: С Exception нужно быть аккуратным, так как палка о двух концах - для простых програм не стоит, для более сложных наверное стоит, но к этому нужно привыкать. Где-то они удобны, а где-то не очень (понимание где-как приходит с опытом)